# Javascript popupWindow and fill some web form field

Tags: javascript, webforms, fill, popupwindow

I'm trying to write a script to popup a web form and then auto fill the form field with some data.

I'm using jQuery popupWindow to popup the page but I don't have any idea how to fill that form field.

Here a example http://jsfiddle.net/moreno/EHhpk/1/

note.: The form field are in an external server and I don't have access to their code.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely certain how you would handle this using that jQuery library, but if you use the old-school...

window.open(...)

...method, it will return a reference to window that has a document property.  Assuming the new window is within the same domain, you should be able to edit the form elements that way.

There's enough example code here to get started:

http://www.javascript-coder.com/window-popup/javascript-window-open.phtml